# Is serving a bot-friendly page to google-bot likely ot adversly affect SEO?

Tags: seo

I have a site which has a homepage that contains a great deal of javascript. I am concious that this isn't great for mobile clients, javascript-less browsers and crawlers/bots. The page uses propper <noscript /> alternatives, alt attributes, etc.

The user-agent can easily be sniffed to serve up a the page content without Javascript (there is a non-javascript version of the content already on the site), but I don't want to be seen to be cheating to crawlers (google-bot).

Humans that use mobile-clients and javascript-less browsers would surely appreciate a tailored version (given an option to switch back to the full version if they want). Bots might think they're being cheated.

Finally, the site has been indexed very well so far, so I am tempted to not tailor it for google-bot, just for humans that use mobile clients and javascript-less browsers. It seems like a safer option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you serve different content to the search engines then you do your users you are cloaking and definitely in violation of Google's terms of service.

The proper way to handle generated with JavaScript is to use progressive enhancement. This means that all of your content is available without JavaScript being required to fetch or display it. Then you enhance that content using JavaScript. This way everyone has access to the same content but users with JavaScript get a better experience. This is good usability and good for SEO.

Comment: John, thank you very much for an informed and insightful response.